# Sending an image to API endpoint

Tags: python

The problem I am facing is when I make the post request and send the read image over, the formatting of the image raising an error and have no idea how to get the image over so it can e processed.

```
##### My request
import cv2
import requests

plate = "plate_1.png"
img = cv2.imread(plate)
url = f"http://127.0.0.1:5000/get-user?extra={img}"

r = requests.post(url)
print(r.text)


######### This is my code at the endpoint

from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/get-user", methods=["POST"])

def get_user():
    extra = request.args.get("extra")
    img = np.array(extra)
    image = cv2.UMat(img)

    return read_image(image)
def home():
    return "Home"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)``
```

Comment: _"raising an error"_ - _what_ error? Quote error messages verbatim.

Comment: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'UMat'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Argument 'usageFlags' is required to be an integer
>  - UMat() missing required argument 'cols' (pos 2)
>  - UMat() missing required argument 'type' (pos 2)
>  - UMat() missing required argument 'cols' (pos 2)
>  - UMat() missing required argument 'type' (pos 2)
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'm'
>  - UMat() missing required argument 'rowRange' (pos 2)
>  - UMat() missing required argument 'roi' (pos 2)
>  - UMat() missing required argument 'ranges' (pos 2)

Comment: Have you checked what your `url` variable actually contains? I really rather doubt that the result of `cv2.imread` is something that can just be concatenated into a string value like that ...?

Comment: And why are you trying to send the image data as a GET parameter in the first place, instead of POST?

Comment: I've tried alot of different things but the problem occurs when i send the cv2.read image over on the receiving end its read as an src and even if I np.array the file it still wobt work. so at this point I just dont know

Comment: Start by checking what I asked you to.

Comment: _"when i send the cv2.read image over on the receiving end its read as an src"_ - I have no idea what that is even supposed to mean, "read as an src" ...?!?

Comment: when I did with post parameters I still encountered the same porblem

Comment: I asked you to verify what `url` actually contains with the above code.

Comment: if I remove the Umat line this is the error I get

Comment: > Overload resolution failed:
>  - src data type = 19 is not supported
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Comment: maybe ignore the code for now. how should I form the request to send the image to my endpoint where I can then process it

Comment: how do I make it into a post request form properly

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an image directly in a URL, but we can convert it into a string that can be sent over HTTP, then convert it back into an image on the server side.

Here is how you can do this:

On the client side, read the image, encode it into a JPEG, and convert it into a string:

```py
import cv2
import requests
import numpy as np

plate = "plate_1.png"
img = cv2.imread(plate)
_, img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)
img_string = img_encoded.tostring()
```

Then, send this string in the body of the POST request:

```py
url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/get-user"
headers = {'content-type': 'image/jpeg'}
r = requests.post(url, data=img_string, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

On the server side, get the data from the request, convert it back into an image:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import numpy as np
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/get-user", methods=["POST"])
def get_user():
    img_string = request.data
    img_array = np.fromstring(img_string, np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(img_array, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return 'Success!'
```

You now should be able to send an image over a POST request and process it on the server.